# Corona: how to capture a screen in corona?

Tags: lua, screenshot, coronasdk, 2d-games

Can anyone suggest how to capture a screen in corona both full screen and particular portion of it?

Comment: http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/displaycapturescreen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It will work :

```
    local function captureDeviceScreen()
       local captured_image = display.captureScreen( true )
       captured_image:scale(.5,.5)
       local alert = native.showAlert( "Success", "Captured Image is Saved to Library", { "OK" } )
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener("tap",captureDeviceScreen)
```

Answer (score 3):

A [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20to%20capture%20a%20screen%20in%20corona?&oq=how%20to%20capture%20a%20screen%20in%20corona?&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.545&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) search produced this link: [How to capture a screen in corona](http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/displaycapturescreen)

If you are having issues with an implementation then please provide more information and perhaps say what you have tried so far so we know where to go next.