# ScreenShot (CORONA SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have to take screenshot of desired screen group but it is not working and totally black image is saved in documents directory . How can I save the screenshot ?

```
local function takeSnapshot(event)
  timer.performWithDelay( 100, captureWithDelay )
end
function captureWithDelay()
  local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
  display.save( stageGroup, "entireGroup.jpg", baseDir )
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corona: how to capture a screen in corona?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355806/corona-how-to-capture-a-screen-in-corona)

Comment: I guess, your stageGroup is empty or just a black screen. Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

For saving a display group,  you have to:

- First create a `display group`.
- Then `add` the screen objects to that group.
- `Return` the display group
- Use `display.save` to save the entire group displayed.

I am giving a sample here:

```
-- creating the display group --
local stageGroup = display.newGroup()  

-- creating display objects and adding it to the group --
local bg = display.newRect(0,0,_w,_h)
bg.x = 160
bg.y = 240
bg:setFillColor(150)
localGroup:insert(bg)

local rect = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
rect.x = 30+math.random(260)
rect.y = 30+math.random(420)
localGroup:insert(rect)

-- Then do as follows --
local function takePhoto()
    -- take screen shot to baseDirectory --
    local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
    display.save( stageGroup, "myScreenshot.jpg", baseDir )
end
rect:addEventListener("tap",takePhoto)
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have added the objects to be appear on the screenshot to the stageGroup.

Keep Coding............. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you using lower version of graphics drive.Try it in Mac latest.