# Capture Screen on Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I tried many ways to capture the screen using corona sdk , i read 
   http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/captureScreen.html

[Corona: how to capture a screen in corona?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355806/corona-how-to-capture-a-screen-in-corona)

However when i run the program , Corona sdk freezes and im obliged to close it
   I am using Corona SDK for windows ,and sometimes I get  "runtime error R6025 PURE virtual function call" , I tried lots of sample codes that have worked with others here is my code

```
_W = display.viewableContentWidth
_H = display.viewableContentHeight
local background = display.newRect(0, 0, 320, 480);
background:setFillColor(255,255,255);
local foo = display.newImageRect("images/foo.png",100,100);
foo.anchorX=0.5
foo.anchorY=0.5
foo.x = _W * 0.5;
foo.y = _H * 0.5;
local screenShot = display.captureScreen(true);
foo:removeSelf();
background:removeSelf();
screenShot.xScale = 0.5;
screenShot.yScale = 0.5;
screenShot.rotation = 45;
```

this is my build.settings file

```
androidPermissions =    
{
    "android.permission.VIBRATE",
    "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
},
```

Comment: this was tested on corona version 2013.2100 , however when I tested on version 2013.1202 it worked fine , anyone knows any reason why this is happening?

Comment: There were some bugs in the release of Graphics 2.0 around screen capture.  They should be all out now, so if you are a Pro or Enterprise subscriber the latest daily build (2187) should work.  This build is the release candidate for the next public build, so hopefully all of these fixes will be available for Starter and Basic accounts soon.

Comment: Thank you , so its a bug , and it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using `display.save` to save the screen to a file.

Check out [Lerg's code](https://gist.github.com/Lerg/8906864) for doing that

This code will save a screenshot in the simulator when the 's' key is pressed

```
if app.isSimulator then
    Runtime:addEventListener('key', function (event)
        if event.keyName == 's' and event.phase == 'down' then
            local scene = storyboard.getScene(storyboard.getCurrentSceneName())
            if scene and scene.view then
                display.save(scene.view, display.pixelWidth .. 'x' .. display.pixelHeight .. '_' .. math.floor(system.getTimer()) .. '.png')
                return true
            end
         end
    end)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display.save() function to save a screenshot from given display group that passed as first argument of function